# I am really confused about NEW keyword use in C# and MVC

Tags: c#

What I know  about new are as follows
1) when creating object in class ,array list etc for example:

```
public class Employee {
public int ID {get;set;}
Public String Name{get;set;}
}


}
public static main(){
var emp n = new Employee;

}
```

2) Modifier

```
public class BaseC
{
    public static int x = 55;
    public static int y = 22;
}

public class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    // Hide field 'x'. 
    new public static int x = 100;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Display the new value of x:
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        // Display the hidden value of x:
        Console.WriteLine(BaseC.x);

        // Display the unhidden member y:
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
/*
Output:
100
55
22
*/
```

but I am going to show some scenario where I feel difficult how the new key word is implementing here . I think first new word is used to create manager object but what is the use of second new or `(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>`. Ccould you explain it please.

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

how is the new keyword used to invoke this statement below:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual question is how

```
ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

could be interpreted, right?

pretty straightforward:

you create a new **Userstore Of a specific Type T** where **T** is an Application user

so

```
UserStore<ApplicationUser> myStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
```

this is just what you mentaioned as 1), nothing special except for the generic "of T".
In your specific case we use an overload where we use the constructor which takes a contecxt object

```
UserStore<ApplicationUser> myStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

After that you use this newly created object in your application manager (altough I think you example is missing something)

```
ApplicationUserManager(myStore);
```

The initial code above is a simple one liner because you wouldn`t need the myStore object.

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' keyword in c# is used for following reasons:

1. You want to allocate memory (create object) in managed heap for your new object
2. You want to replace method in base class with new method of same name
3. Constraints of Generic types (it means that object will be created INSIDE generic method)

Examples :

1. A instance = new A();
2. class A 
      { public void MyMethod() {} }

   class B : A 
      { public new void MyMethod() {} }
3. Class C where MyType : new() {   T instance = new T();  }

Comment: I think that allocation internals is too confusing to OP that does not understand `new` keyword. Better say that `new` is used to create instance.

Answer (score 0):

Mentally translate the "new" used within a member declaration to "hide-base-class-member".

Answer (score 0):

The first example is used to construct a new instance of an object.

The second example is used to replace a field when defining a subclass.

Fields can be accessed by subclasses, so when you try and access the field 'x', it's always the one from the base class.

But what if you have a real need for the field x to refer to something different in the subclass? Putting the `new` modifier means that a unqualified usage of `x` refers to the `x` field in this class, not the superclass (you can use `base.x` to refer to that one).

This main use case for this version of the `new` keyword is method declarations, where it comes in handy for interface implementations, and especially handy for multiple interface implementations.

You can have a method `X()` defined on the interface, and another method `new X()` on the implementation class, and the right method will get called depending on the type of the reference... casting from an interface to the implementation class will cause a different method to be called.

Comment: could you explain  the use of new keyword in this example?  var result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));

Answer (score 0):

In very short: `new [Classname]` calls a Constructor of a Class (e.g. your `new Employee`) and creates an object in an allocated memory space, `new` in front of a variable/method declaration (e.g. `new public static int x = 100;`) is used to "hide" a previous declaration.

The Syntax for `new Employee` is wrong:

```
var emp n = new Employee;
```

should be

```
var emp = new Employee();
```

`var`: type of the variable (that is a variable type the compiler detects but could also be `Employee`)

`emp`: the name of the varibale pointing to the instance

`Employee()`: The class name and the `()` for the empty constructor to call (this is created by default if you don't have specified one.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN reference:

> In C#, the new keyword can be used as an operator, a modifier, or a constraint.

`new as an Operator:`

```
    Used to create objects and invoke constructors.
```

`new as a Modifier:`

```
    Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.
```

`new as a Constraint:`

```
   Used to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type 
   parameter in a generic declaration.
```

In the line:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

You are creating a "new" `ApplicationUserManager`